# libnetfilter_queue programming , how can i know which program send the packet?

Tags: linux, netfilter

I'm trying to make an application level firewall for Linux , but for now i could only tell stuff like ip address , port number.

Is it possible to know which program send the packet ? If i don't need to place a kernel module.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time. The three cases:

- input paath: The socket lookup has not been done yet by the time xtables runs
- forward path: There obviously is no local socket
- (local) output path: Neither the process info nor the socket info is passed onto nf_queue, though there was a [patch proposed](http://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600) but has not received much attention.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be possible to use a netfilter mark on the packet (in a rule which runs before the NFQUEUE) and retrieve it with nfq_get_nfmark. I've not tried it and I don't know if it would work.