# Get uid of packet with libpcap

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, libpcap

Is it possible to get the effective uid of a captured tcp packet with libpcap? In other words, can I use libpcap to get the user id of whomever created said packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the packet was sent from another computer, there is no guarantee that whoever sent the packet *has* a user ID - it might have, for example, been sent by a small embedded operating system that has no notion of user IDs.

If the packet was sent from *your* computer, libpcap can't, by itself, tell you the user ID of who sent it.  However, if you parse the TCP packet, you can get the source IP address and port number of the packet and, depending on the operating system on which you're running, you might be able to get a table of all active TCP connections on your machine, perhaps with a process ID or user ID associated with it.  (Note, however, that, for example, on a UN*X system, a given file descriptor for a given TCP connection can be shared by multiple processes running with different effective or real user IDs, in which case if all you have is the transmitted packet as captured using libpcap, you wouldn't have enough information to determine the user ID, effective or real, of the process that sent the packet, as you wouldn't know the process that sent the packet.)

Comment: That is my dilemma. Originally, I was going to do what you have suggested, but, I only have the packet. My problem is I'm trying to track urls visited by users, the approach you described works in 90% of cases. But, when there are two users going to different pages of the same site, I can't know who went where.

Comment: That type of tracking would only work when running on the user's machine. Unless the HTTP requests include information that identifies users, there is no way you can track URLs visited by users with software running on the server or doing third-party capture on the network.

Comment: The software __is__ running on the user's computer

Comment: I.e., the user's computer has more than one user.  The users will presumably be using different browser instances, and thus will be visiting that site with different connections and thus different local endpoints, so you *can* know who went where.  (If they're using the *same* browser instance, they look like the *same* user to the computer, so the problem is insoluble in that case.)

Comment: I can tell that there are more than one user accessing a **server**, but I can't match which user went to which page, unless there is a time stamp on the connection, then maybe I could do it, based upon the similarity to the timestamp of capturing the packet.

Comment: If you know that, at time T, there's a connection for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PPPP1 to a server, opened by process QQ1 with user ID UU1, and a connection for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PPPP2 to the server, opened by process QQ2 with user ID UU2, then a TCP packet from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PPPP1 to that server probably came from user UU1 rather than user UU2.

Comment: That's the idea! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Note, by the way, that you'll need to look through the connections in, for example, `/proc/net/tcp` each time you see a packet that isn't part of a connection you already know about - the information will be there only as long as the connection is up.

Comment: BTW, the entries in `/proc/net/tcp` appear to include a UID, so you may be able to skip the process lookup if you only want a UID.  I'm ot sure what the UID represents, however.

Comment: /proc/net/tcp is not the way to go for this. I'm using netlink and the inet_diag module. Like ss.

Answer (score 2):

No, the UID info - if there is any to start with - is not propagated through the AF_PACKET channel that pcap uses.

Comment: So it would be necessary to use netfilter?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708471/libnetfilter-queue-programming-how-can-i-know-which-program-send-the-packet/8711193

Answer (score 0):

An eBPF receive filter attached (using SO_ATTACH_BPF) to the AF_PACKET socket (obtained using `pcap_fileno()`) can use `bpf_get_socket_uid(skb)` to get the owner uid of the local socket (if any) associated with the packet. The main problem is how to get this info to userspace...

The easiest way would be to create a separate capture for each user you want to monitor and add an eBPF filter to match only that uid. But obviously this doesn't exactly scale well with the number of users, and it requires you have a specific list of uids you're interested in.

My next idea was you could append/prepend the uid to the packet delivered to userspace (and then patch libpcap to extract it) but unfortunately this type of eBPF filter (BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER) isn't allowed to modify packets.

That leaves using some out-of-band method to deliver the info to userspace, e.g. for each TCP SYN packet you could send the socket uid together with enough info to uniquely identify the connection (src ip, dst ip, src port, dst port) to userspace via an [eBPF ringbuffer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/bpf/ringbuf.html).